# Error while using clusterMaker2 Cytoscape

Tags: cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, cytoscape

I am using the clusterMaker2 app on Cytoscape to create a network and am getting this error message.
Cannot invoke "edu.ucsf.rbvi.clusterMaker2.internal.api.ClusterManager.getNetwork()" because "manager" is full.
What does this error message mean and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

I tried to run Cytoscape again

Comment: Wow!  I've never seen that error.  Can you tell me exactly the steps to reproduce this error?  Which algorithm were you trying to run?  What does your network look like? etc.  Also, there should be a traceback in your framework log (~/CytoscapeConfiguration/3/framework-cytoscape.log) -- that would be helpful also.   -- scooter